# Spree add discount price to variant

Tags: spree

I'm new on spree and I read that a product has a master variant that contains the price attribute. I have to add a "discount price" to the master variant.

I can simply add the column to the variant model and modify manually the view but I think that it is not the best approach because I suppose this column should modify the behavior of checkout process (instead of the master price I need to show the discount price if it is present).

Which is the best strategy to work out the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a couple of options here:

- If the discount applies to individual items, you may want to consider storing that price in the line_items.price field rather than the variant. The line item price is copied from the variant price, but it can be adjusted to whatever discount price you'd want to set without affecting the variant. Meaning, a discount code could have an arbitrary percentage off on that item, and the line_item price would be updated to reflect that discount percentage.
- If the discount applies to the whole order, it could be added as an adjustment / credit, which is how the promo gem works.

At any rate, I would probably not recommend storing it in the variant data model and I would suggest looking into the functionality supported by the promo core gem.

Comment: the discount is applied to individual items, for example product A price:10, discount price: 8. Do you suggest to add the column discount_price to line_items object? Thank you

Comment: No, I do not suggest creating an additional column. I suggest to add a calculator based on other similar Spree calculators and just updating the line_item.price column.